# How to edit the ticks in jointplot or JointGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, xticks, jointplot

How can I change the tick placement in a seaborn jointplot or JointGrid?

I'm looking for something similar to matplotlib's `plt.xticks`.

Answer (score 18):

You can access the 'axes' of a `JointGrid` object using `ax_joint` (for the main plot) and `ax_marg_x` or `ax_marg_y` for the marginal distributions' plots. Then, you can use the [full API for the matplotlib axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) to manipulate the details of the plot, and in particular you can use the `get_xticks`/`set_xticks` to change the tick placement.

Here's a basic example of how to use this to change the xticks/yticks positions:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.jointplot(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100))

g.ax_joint.set_xticks([0, 0.34, 0.88])
g.ax_joint.set_yticks([-0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.1])
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: Example of a seaborn jointplot with modified ticks]

Comment: if you want to rotate the ticks:


    `for tick in ax.ax_joint.get_xticklabels():
        tick.set_rotation(30)`

Comment: Due to axis rotation, my x label disappears. any tricks to visualize it back?